# How do I install Polly?

Tags: installation, twitter

So I was reading over on [OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/07/schizobird/) about this new Ubuntu twitter client called "[Polly](https://launchpad.net/polly)", and I was wondering how to install it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### The easy way

Polly recently added a PPA - to add it, run the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:conscioususer/polly-daily && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install polly
```

Then, just select "Polly" to run from the Unity Dash, or run `polly` from a terminal if you want to catch the messages/output/etc.

---

**Outdated instructions that are being kept for future reference:**

Fairly simple to run it. This won't install it properly, it'll just download the python files to your home directory and run them. But it works.

```
cd ~
sudo apt-get install python-socksipy python-oauth2 python-numpy bzr
bzr branch lp:polly

~/polly/polly
```

If you want to make a launcher, just have it run `~/polly/polly` or `/home/username/polly/polly`.

You'll want to keep it updated on a regular basis. To do that, run:

```
cd ~/polly && bzr update
```