# Twitter desktop client

Tags: software-recommendation, twitter

What is a good twitter desktop client for Ubuntu 12.04?

I've used to use corebird for 14.04 and 14.10. But it's some how buggy and it's not available for Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few (though I have not tried all of them in 12.04):

1. [Gwibber](https://launchpad.net/gwibber)

   To install this, run the following code in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gwibber
   ```

   although a post [Install latest Gwibber (friends-app) in Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322795/install-latest-gwibber-friends-app-in-ubuntu-12-04) says that the package is broken (I have not tested this)
2. [Polly](https://launchpad.net/polly) - supports in-line images

   To install this, run the following code in the terminal (more info is available at [How do I install Polly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54459/how-do-i-install-polly)):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:conscioususer/polly-daily
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install polly
   ```
3. [Turpial](http://turpial.org.ve/) - supports multi-column layout and multi-account

   To install this run the following codes in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install turpial
   ```
4. [TTYtter](http://www.floodgap.com/software/ttytter/) CLI, but not currently under development I guess

   To use this, first download the perl script from [here](http://www.floodgap.com/software/ttytter/dl.html) to a location on your computer from where you want to run it. Then make it executable with:

   ```
   chmod +x <path/to/script-file>
   ```

   and run it with:

   ```
   ./ttytter
   ```
5. [Birdie](https://launchpad.net/~birdie-team/+archive/ubuntu/stable) - Reported to be buggy in 12.04 but worth a try

   To install this, run the following commands in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:birdie-team/stable
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install birdie
   ```

Comment: To list how to install would be perfect answer for newbies to get help